# Prevent Grafana alerts during weekends and holidays

Tags: alert, grafana

## Background

We're using Grafana alerts.
During weekends and holidays, some of our metrics are lower and that's actually ok. But only during those days.

## Problem

During weekends and holidays we receive alerts from Grafana even though the system is actually ok.

## Question

How can we prevent Grafana from alerting us on certain metrics during weekends and holidays?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope. You might want to try using PagerDuty.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6592#issuecomment-389119647) discussion could help

Answer (score 1):

Grafana does not support that natively but [here](https://github.com/allangood/holiday_exporter#solution-2) you can find a not-very difficult solution.